# Jquery modal dialog pop up- Fix in center of the screen in all browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I need to display the popup when the page loads. I am getting the popup but the problem is the popup dialog is coming center of the screen in IE. But in firefox and chrome it appears slight down.(i.e: it comes center of the screen- the page is too long). But I want it to stay center of the screen in Firefox and chrome.

Please try in chrome.

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {  
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
         width : 710,
         height : 410,
         modal: true   
        });   
    });
</script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> 

<style>
    .ui-dialog-titlebar {
        height: 15px;
 }
</style>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dialog" style="display:none;" title=" ">
        <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="670" height="350" src="popUp.html"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
 $(function() { 
   var dlog= $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
         width : 710,
         height : 350,
         modal: true 
   /*,position:{
   my: 'center',
            at: 'center',
   of:window
   }  not working I do not know why may be the version of jquery */
        }); 
  
 var objpos = { left: ($(window).width() - $( "#dialog" ).closest('.ui-dialog').width()) / 2, top:(window.innerHeight- $( "#dialog" ).closest('.ui-dialog').height())/2 }
//$( ".ui-dialog" ).dialog('option', 'position', [objpos.left, objpos.top]);   not working I do not know why may be the version of jquery
$( "#dialog" ).closest('.ui-dialog').css({ top: objpos.top+ 'px',left:objpos.left+"px" });
  });
```

```css
 .ui-dialog-titlebar {
        height: 15px;
 }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dialog" style="display:none;" title=" ">
        <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="670" height="350" src="popUp.html"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```